# QDialog is blank with show command

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008

If I create my QDialog and show it modal with exec() everything works fine, but I need this no modal!

With show() the Dialog is **empty**!

```
ProgramLoading *programLoading = new ProgramLoading();  
programLoading->show(); 

// some code

programLoading->done(0);
```

Constructor

```
ProgramLoading::ProgramLoading(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint ); // remove window border
}
```

Don't think something with Dialog code is wrong because it works with exec()!

Any hints? Thank you!

PS: I'm using QT plugin for VisualStudio 2008

Comment: The non-modal dialog can be regarded as an extension of your main window, at least it should display something that created by constructor after `show()` is called. Care to share what've you done to the poor `QDialog`?

Comment: Is there some blocking loop in the `// some code` part?

Comment: I added constructor code! @thuga no

Comment: Show us the code from _done()_

Comment: @Zlatomir [`QDialog::done`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#done).

Comment: @leon22 So you are showing your dialog and almost immediately after you call `programLoading->done(0);` which closes the dialog?

Comment: Note that exec() blocks until the dialog closes, show() just shows it. You must enter the event loop and not call done() immediately to have anything shown.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour though its strange. After taking a small look into it, it just did not load my graphics i placed there. All other UI-Elements are being shown.

Comment: Comment by @FrankOsterfeld is correct, if i open and close both in MW-Constructor im only getting a busy-widget (empty non-interactive and busy) as dialog. move your initialisation in an init function so event loop is already running. Otherwise you could eventually open a SplashWidget in main already, never tried though.

Comment: @SebastianLange All I get is a dialog that opens and closes immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mw (Default with Window Decoration):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    sd = new SplashDialog();
    sd->show();

    QTimer::singleShot(10000,this,SLOT(closeSplashDialog()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::closeSplashDialog()
{
    sd->close();
    delete sd;
}
```

splash (UI having Label and Button):

```
SplashDialog::SplashDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SplashDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint );
}

SplashDialog::~SplashDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Splash Dialog opens and is being closed 10 seconds later as intended

Comment: Thx! Note: Declare ProgramLoading as member of MainWindow and everything works fine!